# Orphan users in all databases on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know this sp returns Orphanded users :
EXEC sp_change_users_login @Action='Report'

I try to find Orphaned users in all databases on SQL Server but it's not returns true result.

```
    DECLARE @name  NVARCHAR(MAX),@sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql2 NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @dbname  NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE Crs CURSOR
    FOR

SELECT name FROM sys.sysdatabases where dbid>4 and name not in(
SELECT  DB_NAME(dr_state.database_id) as name
FROM (( sys.availability_groups AS ag JOIN sys.availability_replicas AS ar ON ag.group_id = ar.group_id )
JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states AS ar_state ON ar.replica_id = ar_state.replica_id)
JOIN sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states dr_state on ag.group_id = dr_state.group_id
and dr_state.replica_id = ar_state.replica_id
where ar_state.role_desc='SECONDARY' AND ar_state.is_local=1
)
OPEN Crs
FETCH NEXT FROM Crs INTO @Name

/*WHILE @@ FETCH_STATUS = 0 It means keep returning the cursor by moving to the next record until there are no records left to circulate in the cursor.*/

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
BEGIN   

    SELECT name FROM sys.sysdatabases where name=@name 
    select @dbname=name from sysdatabases where name=@name 

    use @dbname
    EXEC sp_change_users_login @Action='Report'
 FETCH NEXT FROM Crs INTO @Name
 END     

/*CLOSE ve DEALLOCATE commad closed Cursor*/
CLOSE Crs
DEALLOCATE Crs
```

my error:Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 49
Incorrect syntax near '@dbname'.

If I assign the database name to the @dbname variable, the problem will be solved.
Thanks.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for this, you cannot do `use @param` it needs to be a literal string. Use `sp_executesql` and pass through any other parameters you need, use `QUOTENAME(@dbname)` for the database

Comment: What are you *really* trying to achieve here? You say you're trying to find the orphaned `USER`s, but what are you planning to do with those `USER`s? Also `sp_change_users_login` is deprecated (and has been for some time): [sp_change_users_login (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-change-users-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). You should really be using `ALTER USER`.

Comment: You're not the first person to have and try to solve this problem. I've used https://docs.dbatools.io/#Get-DbaDbOrphanUser and https://docs.dbatools.io/#Repair-DbaDbOrphanUser to find and repair (respectively) orphan users. They work really well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, to me, that you just want to list all the Users, in your databases, that don't have a related `LOGIN`, excluding Loginless objects. As I mentioned `sp_change_users_login` is deprecated, so you shouldn't be using that, but you can get the information from the `sys.database_principles` and `sys.server_principles` objects. So for a single database you could do something like this:

```sql
SELECT db_name(),
       dp.[name] AS UserName,
       dp.[sid] AS UserSID
FROM sys.database_principals dp
WHERE dp.[type] IN ('U','S')
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM sys.server_principals sp
                  WHERE sp.sid = dp.sid)
  AND authentication_type > 0;
```

I'm going to (shamelessly) us my `sp_foreachdatabase` proc ([A CURSOR free version of sp_msforeachdb](https://wp.larnu.uk/a-cursor-free-version-of-sp_msforeachdb/)) and then use the dynamic SQL to put all the data into a single temporary table, and `SELECT` that at the end. This gives something like this (I have included definition of my objects at the end of this answer):

```sql
DECLARE @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

DECLARE @PreCommand nvarchar(MAX) = N'CREATE TABLE #Orphans (DBName sysname,' + @CRLF +
                                    N'                       UserName sysname,' + @CRLF +
                                    N'                       UserSID varbinary(85));';
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(MAX) = N'INSERT INTO #Orphans (DBName, UserName, UserSID)' + @CRLF +
                                 N'SELECT db_name(),' + @CRLF +
                                 N'       dp.[name] AS UserName,' + @CRLF +
                                 N'       dp.[sid] AS UserSID' + @CRLF +
                                 N'FROM sys.database_principals dp' + @CRLF +
                                 N'WHERE dp.[type] IN (''U'',''S'')' + @CRLF +
                                 N'  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1' + @CRLF +
                                 N'                  FROM sys.server_principals sp' + @CRLF +
                                 N'                  WHERE sp.sid = dp.sid)' + @CRLF +
                                 N'  AND authentication_type > 0;';
DECLARE @PostCommand nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT DBName, UserName, UserSID FROM #Orphans; DROP TABLE #Orphans;';

DECLARE @CommandRun nvarchar(MAX);
EXEC master.dbo.sp_foreachdatabase @Pre_Command = @PreCommand,
                                   @Command = @Command,
                                   @Post_Command = @PostCommand,
                                   @Exit_On_Error = 0,
                                   @Skip_System = 1,
                                   @Auto_Use = 1,
                                   @Command_Run = @CommandRun OUTPUT;
```

This puts all the orphaned users into temporary table, with their database's name, and then `SELECT`s them at the end.

*Object definitions:*

```sql
USE master;
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.types WHERE [name] = N'objectlist')
    CREATE TYPE dbo.objectlist AS table ([name] sysname);
GO
USE master;
GO
CREATE OR ALTER PROC sp_foreachdatabase @Command nvarchar(MAX),
                                        @Delimit_Character nchar(1) = N'?', --Character to be replaced with a delimit identified version of the datbaase name I.e. [master]
                                        @Quote_Character nchar(1) = N'&', --Character to be replaced with a single quoted (') version of the datbaase name I.e. 'master'
                                        @Skip_System bit = 0, --Omits master, msdb, tempdb and model. Ignored if @Database_List has data.
                                        @Skip_User bit = 0, --Omits all user databases. Ignored if @Database_List has data.
                                        @Database_List dbo.objectlist READONLY, --If @Skip_System and @Skip_User equal 1, and this is empty, an error will be thrown
                                        @Auto_Use bit = 0, --Automatically starts each command agaisnt a database with a USE
                                        @Exit_On_Error bit = 1, --If an error is occurs against a single database, the command will still be run against the remainder. Otherwise everything is rolled back
                                                                --This does not effect the @Pre_Command and @Post_Command statements
                                        @Pre_Command nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, --Command to run before @Command. Does not use Character Replacements. Run against master DB.
                                        @Post_Command nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, --Command to run after @Command. Does not use Character Replacements. Run against master DB.
                                        @Command_Run nvarchar(MAX) = NULL OUTPUT  --Returns the generated and replaced command, for trouble shooting
AS BEGIN
 
    --Do some checking of passed values first
    --Check that @Skip_System, @Skip_User aren't both 0 or that @Database_List has some rows
    IF (@Skip_System = 1 AND @Skip_User = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Database_List))
        THROW 62401, N'System and User databases cannot be skipped if a Database List is not supplied.', 16;
         
    IF @Delimit_Character IS NULL OR @Delimit_Character = ''
        THROW 62402, N'@Delimit_Character cannot have a value of NULL or ''''.', 16;

    IF @Quote_Character IS NULL OR @Quote_Character = ''
        THROW 62403, N'@Quote_Character cannot have a value of NULL or ''''.', 16; 
 
    IF @Skip_User IS NULL
        THROW 62404, N'@Skip_User cannot have a value of NULL.', 16;
 
    IF @Skip_System IS NULL
        THROW 62405, N'@Skip_System cannot have a value of NULL.', 16;
 
    IF @Auto_Use IS NULL
        PRINT N'@Auto_Use has a value of NULL. Behaviour will be as if the value is 0.';
 
    DECLARE @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
    DECLARE @RC int;
 
    --Add the Pre Command to the batch
    SET @Command_Run = ISNULL(N'/* --- Pre Command Begin. --- */' + @CRLF + @CRLF + N'USE master;' + @CRLF + @CRLF + @Pre_Command + @CRLF + @CRLF + N'/* --- Pre Command End. --- */', N'');
 
    --Get the databases we need to deal with
    --As @Database_List might be empty and it's READONLY, and we're going to do the command in database_id order we need another variable.
    DECLARE @DBs table (database_id int,
                        database_name sysname);
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Database_List)
        INSERT INTO @DBs (database_id,database_name)
        SELECT d.database_id,
               d.[name]
        FROM sys.databases d
             JOIN @Database_List DL ON d.[name] = DL.[name];
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO @DBs (database_id,database_name)
        SELECT d.database_id,
               d.[name]
        FROM sys.databases d
        WHERE (d.database_id <= 4 AND @Skip_System = 0) OR (d.database_id > 4 AND @Skip_User = 0);
 
    SET @Command_Run = @Command_Run + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                       N'/* --- Begin command for each database. --- */' + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                       CASE WHEN @Exit_On_Error = 0 THEN N'--Turning XACT_ABORT off due to @Exit_On_Error parameter' + @CRLF + @CRLF + N'SET XACT_ABORT OFF;' + @CRLF + N'DECLARE @Error nvarchar(4000);' ELSE N'SET XACT_ABORT ON;' END +
                       (SELECT @CRLF + @CRLF + 
                               N'/* --- Running @Command against database ' + QUOTENAME(DB.database_name,'''') + N'. --- */' + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                               CASE WHEN @Auto_Use = 1 THEN N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(DB.database_name) + N';' + @CRLF + @CRLF ELSE N'' END +
                               N'BEGIN TRY' + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                               REPLACE(REPLACE(@Command, @Delimit_Character, QUOTENAME(DB.database_name)),@Quote_Character, 'N' + QUOTENAME(DB.database_name,'''')) + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                               'END TRY' + @CRLF +
                               N'BEGIN CATCH' + @CRLF +
                               CASE WHEN @Exit_On_Error = 0 THEN N'    SET @Error = N''The following error occured during the batch, but has been skipped:'' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + ' + @CRLF +
                                                                 N'                 N''Msg '' + CONVERT(nvarchar(6),ERROR_NUMBER()) + '', Level '' + CONVERT(nvarchar(6),ERROR_SEVERITY()) + '', State '' + CONVERT(nvarchar(6),ERROR_STATE()) + '', Line '' + CONVERT(nvarchar(6),ERROR_LINE()) + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +' + @CRLF + 
                                                                 N'                 ERROR_MESSAGE();' + @CRLF +
                                                                 N'    PRINT @Error;' + @CRLF +
                                                                 N'    SET @RC = ERROR_NUMBER();'
                                                            ELSE N'    THROW;'
                               END + @CRLF +
                               N'END CATCH;' + @CRLF +
                               N'/* --- Completed @Command against database ' + QUOTENAME(DB.database_name,'''') + N'. --- */'
                        FROM @DBs DB
                        FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)') + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                        CASE WHEN @Exit_On_Error = 0 THEN N'--Turning XACT_ABORT back on due to @Exit_On_Error parameter' + @CRLF + @CRLF + N'SET XACT_ABORT ON;' ELSE N'' END;
 
    SET @Command_Run = @Command_Run + ISNULL(@CRLF + @CRLF + N'/* --- Post Command Begin. --- */' + @CRLF + @CRLF + N'USE master;' + @CRLF + @CRLF + @Post_Command + @CRLF + @CRLF + N'/* --- Post Command End. --- */', N'');
 
    EXEC sp_executesql @Command_Run, N'@RC int OUTPUT', @RC = @RC;

    SET @RC = ISNULL(@RC, 0);
    RETURN @RC;
 
END;
GO
```

Comment: I'm trying to find Orphaned users in all databases on SQL Server for reporting and  your answer is working thank you so much. @Larnu